# Sql Server JSON result separated in multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, json, azure

I would like to know if this is normal behavior of SQL Server (on Azure).
My SQL query returns JSON using **FOR JSON PATH** and nested queries.
My problem is that **it seems** that depending on the length of the resulting JSON, the result is separated into multiple rows.

This is a problem since the number of rows might change depending on the data. I would also have to concat all the rows together manually to have a valid JSON.

A workaround is to put the resulting JSON into a variable and select it after hand. This results in a single row and column (so I know it is not a max length issue).

Is this normal behavior or is there a problem with my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sql Server splits result of FOR JSON query into ~2KB chunk, so you should either concatenate fragments like on the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn957476.aspx) or you can stream results into some output stream.

Here you can find ASP.NET Core REST API implementation where results of the SQL query with FOR JSON is streamed into response body: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1106622/Building-REST-services-with-ASP-NET-Core-Web-API-a

Comment: Hi, can you please provide a link to the documentation which supports this? I can't seem to find anything in the Microsoft documentation that mentions 2 kb chunking.