# How do you read Json data sent by SQL Server in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, ado.net

I have created a stored procedure which returns JSON data:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SpEmployeeSel 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT ve.*
    FROM dbo.VwEmployee AS ve
    FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
END;
```

This query outputs:

```
[
  {
    "PersonId": 4,
    "FirstName": "Anuj",
    "MiddleName": "",
    "LastName": "Tamrakar",
    "DateofBirth": "2018-01-04T00:00:00",
    "EmployeeId": 1,
    "EmployeeCode": "Emp1",
    "DesignationId": 1,
    "DesignationName": "Ceo",
    "InsertPersonId": 1,
    "InsertDate": "2018-01-20T02:16:00"
  },
  {
    "PersonId": 5,
    "FirstName": "John",
    "MiddleName": "",
    "LastName": "Pradhan",
    "DateofBirth": "2018-01-04T00:00:00",
    "EmployeeId": 2,
    "EmployeeCode": "Emp2",
    "DesignationId": 2,
    "DesignationName": "Human Resource",
    "InsertPersonId": 1,
    "InsertDate": "2018-01-20T02:17:00"
  },
  {
    "PersonId": 6,
    "FirstName": "Priyanka",
    "MiddleName": "",
    "LastName": "Khadgi",
    "DateofBirth": "2018-01-03T00:00:00",
    "EmployeeId": 3,
    "EmployeeCode": "Emp3",
    "DesignationId": 1,
    "DesignationName": "Ceo",
    "InsertPersonId": 1,
    "InsertDate": "2018-01-20T02:16:00"
  },
  {
    "PersonId": 10,
    "FirstName": "Sakar",
    "MiddleName": "",
    "LastName": "Thapa",
    "DateofBirth": "2018-01-09T00:00:00",
    "EmployeeId": 7,
    "EmployeeCode": "Emp4",
    "DesignationId": 1,
    "DesignationName": "Ceo",
    "InsertPersonId": 1,
    "InsertDate": "2018-01-20T02:16:00"
  },
  {
    "PersonId": 11,
    "FirstName": "Aaa",
    "MiddleName": "",
    "LastName": "asdfasf",
    "DateofBirth": "2018-01-03T00:00:00",
    "EmployeeId": 8,
    "EmployeeCode": "Emp5",
    "DesignationId": 2,
    "DesignationName": "Human Resource",
    "InsertPersonId": 1,
    "InsertDate": "2018-01-20T02:17:00"
  },
  {
    "PersonId": 12,
    "FirstName": "Bibek",
    "MiddleName": "",
    "LastName": "Thapa",
    "DateofBirth": "2018-01-11T00:00:00",
    "EmployeeId": 9,
    "EmployeeCode": "Emp6",
    "DesignationId": 3,
    "DesignationName": "Staff",
    "InsertPersonId": 1,
    "InsertDate": "2018-01-20T02:17:00"
  },
  {
    "PersonId": 13,
    "FirstName": "dafgasdf",
    "MiddleName": "",
    "LastName": "asfsdf",
    "DateofBirth": "2018-01-12T00:00:00",
    "EmployeeId": 10,
    "EmployeeCode": "Emp7",
    "DesignationId": 1,
    "DesignationName": "Ceo",
    "InsertPersonId": 1,
    "InsertDate": "2018-01-20T02:16:00"
  },
  {
    "PersonId": 14,
    "FirstName": "sdfsdf",
    "MiddleName": "asdfsdaf",
    "LastName": "asdfasdf",
    "DateofBirth": "2018-01-03T00:00:00",
    "EmployeeId": 11,
    "EmployeeCode": "Emp8",
    "DesignationId": 2,
    "DesignationName": "Human Resource",
    "InsertPersonId": 1,
    "InsertDate": "2018-01-20T02:17:00"
  },
  {
    "PersonId": 15,
    "FirstName": "Asdfasf",
    "MiddleName": "asdf",
    "LastName": "asdfasf",
    "DateofBirth": "2018-01-05T00:00:00",
    "EmployeeId": 12,
    "EmployeeCode": "Emp9",
    "DesignationId": 2,
    "DesignationName": "Human Resource",
    "InsertPersonId": 1,
    "InsertDate": "2018-01-20T02:17:00"
  },
  {
    "PersonId": 16,
    "FirstName": "asdfasf",
    "MiddleName": "aasdfa",
    "LastName": "asdfasf",
    "DateofBirth": "2018-01-12T00:00:00",
    "EmployeeId": 13,
    "EmployeeCode": "Emp10",
    "DesignationId": 1,
    "DesignationName": "Ceo",
    "InsertPersonId": 1,
    "InsertDate": "2018-01-20T02:16:00"
  },
  {
    "PersonId": 17,
    "FirstName": "1111123123",
    "MiddleName": "asdfasd",
    "LastName": "asdfasdf",
    "DateofBirth": "2018-01-05T00:00:00",
    "EmployeeId": 14,
    "EmployeeCode": "Emp11",
    "DesignationId": 2,
    "DesignationName": "Human Resource",
    "InsertPersonId": 1,
    "InsertDate": "2018-01-20T02:17:00"
  }
]
```

You can see the procedure outputs the expected json data in a single column.

Now in Visual Studio, I tried calling the procedure through ADO.NET like this

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("//connection string path");
conn.Open();

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SpEmployeeSEl", conn);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter sta = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
sta.Fill(dt);

conn.Close();

string result = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
```

Now When I look at the output result I only get half of the json data like below:

```
[
  {
    "PersonId": 4,
    "FirstName": "Anuj",
    "MiddleName": "",
    "LastName": "Tamrakar",
    "DateofBirth": "2018-01-04T00:00:00",
    "EmployeeId": 1,
    "EmployeeCode": "Emp1",
    "DesignationId": 1,
    "DesignationName": "Ceo",
    "InsertPersonId": 1,
    "InsertDate": "2018-01-20T02:16:00"
  },
  {
    "PersonId": 5,
    "FirstName": "John",
    "MiddleName": "",
    "LastName": "Pradhan",
    "DateofBirth": "2018-01-04T00:00:00",
    "EmployeeId": 2,
    "EmployeeCode": "Emp2",
    "DesignationId": 2,
    "DesignationName": "Human Resource",
    "InsertPersonId": 1,
    "InsertDate": "2018-01-20T02:17:00"
  },
  {
    "PersonId": 6,
    "FirstName": "Priyanka",
    "MiddleName": "",
    "LastName": "Khadgi",
    "DateofBirth": "2018-01-03T00:00:00",
    "EmployeeId": 3,
    "EmployeeCode": "Emp3",
    "DesignationId": 1,
    "DesignationName": "Ceo",
    "InsertPersonId": 1,
    "InsertDate": "2018-01-20T02:16:00"
  },
  {
    "PersonId": 10,
    "FirstName": "Sakar",
    "MiddleName": "",
    "LastName": "Thapa",
    "DateofBirth": "2018-01-09T00:00:00",
    "EmployeeId": 7,
    "EmployeeCode": "Emp4",
    "DesignationId": 1,
    "DesignationName": "Ceo",
    "InsertPersonId": 1,
    "InsertDate": "2018-01-20T02:16:00"
  },
  {
    "PersonId": 11,
    "FirstName": "Aaa",
    "MiddleName": "",
    "LastName": "asdfasf",
    "DateofBirth": "2018-01-03T00:00:00",
    "EmployeeId": 8,
    "EmployeeCode": "Emp5",
    "DesignationId": 2,
    "DesignationName": "Human Resource",
    "InsertPersonId": 1,
    "InsertDate": "2018-01-20T02:17:00"
  },
  {
    "PersonId": 12,
    "FirstName": "Bibek",
    "MiddleName": "",
    "LastName": "Thapa",
    "DateofBirth": "2018-01-11T00:00:00",
    "EmployeeId": 9,
    "EmployeeCode": "Emp6",
    "DesignationId": 3,
    "DesignationName": "Staff",
    "InsertPersonId": 1,
    "InsertDate": "2018-01-20T02:17:00"
  },
  {
    "PersonId": 13,
    "FirstName": "dafgasdf",
    "MiddleName": "",
    "LastName": "asfsdf",
    "DateofBirth": "2018-01-12T00:00:00",
    "EmployeeId": 10,
    "EmployeeCode": "Emp7",
    "DesignationId": 1,
    "DesignationName": "Ceo",
    "InsertPersonId": 1,
    "InsertDate": "2018-01-20T02:16:00"
  },
  {
    "PersonId": 14,
    "FirstName": "sdfsdf",
    "MiddleName": "asdfsdaf",
    "LastName": "asdfasdf",
    "DateofBirth": "2018-01-03T00:00:00",
    "EmployeeId": 11,
    "EmployeeCode": "Emp8",
    "DesignationId": 2,
    "DesignationName": "Human Resource",
    "InsertPersonId": 1,
    "InsertDate": "2018-01-20T02:17:00"
  },
  {
    "PersonId": 15,
    "FirstName": "Asdfasf",
    "MiddleName": "asdf
```

The json string terminates in middle.

I tried looking the content of dataTable and there the string was broken into two rows which caused the the code `dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()` to return only first row and this is the root cause of the problem.

[image]

So I don't know why the string was broken down into two rows.

I then tried calling the procedure with entity framework like this:

```
string result;

using (AccountingEntities db = new AccountingEntities())
{
    result = db.SpEmployeeSel().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

But the result was same as Ado.Net with broken json string.

I would really be grateful if you guys give solution of Entity Framework rather than in ADO.NET. Since my application uses Entity Framework.

UPDATE:
Workaround That I did  for Entity Framework:

```
string jsonresult;
using (AccountingEntities db = new AccountingEntities())
{
   List<string> jsonlist= db.SpTestSEl().ToList();
   jsonresult = String.Join("", jsonlist.ToArray());
}
```

Workaround that I did for Ado.net :

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/use-for-json-output-in-sql-server-and-in-client-apps-sql-server

Note: Entity framework sucks.

Comment: Read this, see if this applies to your situation: [Sql Server splits result of FOR JSON query into ~2KB chunk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41915103/3677457)

Comment: Just spitballing but maybe the string returned is too long a value for the row column? So maybe it's automatically splitting it into multiple rows for you (and theoretically could be more than 2 rows depending on the data returned). You could just loop through the rows and join the strings together?

Answer (score 2):

I havent tried this whether its working this is one solution i found please try it and see.

```
var queryWithForJson = "SELECT ... FOR JSON";
var conn = new SqlConnection("<connection string>");
var cmd = new SqlCommand(queryWithForJson, conn);
conn.Open();
var jsonResult = new StringBuilder();
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (!reader.HasRows)
{
    jsonResult.Append("[]");
}
else
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        jsonResult.Append(reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/use-for-json-output-in-sql-server-and-in-client-apps-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-4015686#use-for-json-output-in-a-c-client-app