# Map child objects with Dapper

Tags: c#, dapper

I'm trying to return an order with the line items that belong to the order. Currently, only one line item is being returned even if there are more than one. That is because I'm calling `FirstOrDefault()`

The variable result has two records. The only difference between the two is the SKU and the quantity.

How do I map the lineitems? The order object contains a list of LineItem and I need all of them to be added.

```
public async Task<IOrder> ReadAsync(int orderId)
{
  var result = await WithConnection(async c => await c.QueryAsync<Order, LineItem, Order>("_Orders_LineItems_ReadByOrderID", 
    (order, lineitem) =>
    {
      if (order.LineItems == null) order.LineItems = new List<ILineItem>();
      order.LineItems.Add(lineitem);
      return order;
    }, new { orderId }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, splitOn: "LineItemID"));

  return result.FirstOrDefault();   
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what a row of the query result looks like? Are all the line item columns to the right of `LineItemID`?

Answer (score 1):

By using multiple mapping you CAN NOT manage 1:N relationship, as you're trying to do by having one order with more than one line item.

More info here if you're interested: Multiple Mapping [Mapping a single row to multiple objects](https://medium.com/dapper-net/multiple-mapping-d36c637d14fa)

You have two options to solve the problem:

1. Change the stored procedure to return two result sets: `1 for the order`, `1 with "n" associated line items`, and then read each result set (Dapper supports this feature: [Handling Multiple Resultsets](https://medium.com/dapper-net/handling-multiple-resultsets-4b108a8c5172) into Order and LineItem objects.
2. Change the stored procedure to return a JSON that return the orders with nested line items. You can then convert JSON into your object.

My strong suggestion is for the second option if you're using SQL Server 2016 an after that supports JSON natively.

#### 3rd party edit

In case option 1 `multiple resultsets` is of interesst the [provided link](https://medium.com/dapper-net/handling-multiple-resultsets-4b108a8c5172) has this code snippet:

> In any case, if you have multiple resultset, Dapper can help you, via
> the QueryMultiple method

```cs
var results = conn.QueryMultiple(@"
    SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName FROM dbo.Users; 
    SELECT Id, CompanyName FROM dbo.Companies
");
var users = results.Read<User>(); 
var companies = results.Read<Company>();
```

and

> QueryMultiple returns a GridReader object that allows you to access
> the available resultset in sequence, from the first to the last. All
> you have to do is call the Read method, as shown in the above code,

These links from dapper might be usefull as well

- [Dapper - multi-mapping](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/tree/main#multi-mapping)
- [Dapper - multiple-results](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/tree/main#multiple-results)

Comment: Reference to option 2 is here:
https://medium.com/dapper-net/one-to-many-mapping-with-dapper-55ae6a65cfd4

Comment: It seems that second option has a 2033 characters limit on json response.

Comment: Yeah, you need to concatenate the result yourself or put everything into a TSQL variable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41915103/6859967. Here's an example of how to avoid the concatenation issue:
```DECLARE @x NVARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT * FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader FOR JSON AUTO); SELECT @x AS Result;```

Here's a detailed article on this: https://h-savran.blogspot.com/2020/04/challenges-with-returning-data-as-json.html

Comment: Btw, thanks for highlighting this, I'll update the sample ASAP.